# Recorrer un array con un for para validar que no hayan valores repetidos en C

Tags: array, c, bucle-for

Estoy iniciando en c y estoy haciendo un proyecto. Me quede trabado en una parte donde quiero hacer que el DNI ingresado tiene que ser único, se me ocurrió intentando hacer un array donde se compare que el DNI ingresado anteriormente con el actual. EDIT: no logro resolverlo de la correcta manera.
En el código puse la estructura recortada, el nombre de personas en 100 espacios de memoria porque se puede ingresar 100 personas y la función donde esta el problema, lo recorte un poco ya que el codigo es todavía mas grande pero me quede trabado con esto

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct{
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    int dni;
    int tel;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;

}c_persona;

c_persona personas[100];

void cargar(c_persona *puntero_persona){
    int contenedor, j;

    printf("Ingrese el nombre de la persona: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*puntero_persona).nombre );
    printf("Ingrese el apellido de la persona: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*puntero_persona).apellido );
    printf("Ingrese el dni de la persona: ");


    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dni );
    while((*puntero_persona).dni < 10000000 || (*puntero_persona).dni > 99999999){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un dni correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dni );
            }

      for(j = 0;j<100;j++){
        if(contenedor == puntero_persona[j].dni){
            printf("DNI repetido, vuelva a ingresar el dni correctamente: ");
            scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dni );
            contenedor = (*puntero_persona).dni;
        }
    }
 
    printf("Ingrese el telefono de la persona: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).tel );
    while((*puntero_persona).tel < 1000000000 || (*puntero_persona).tel > 9999999999){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un telefono correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).tel );
            }
    printf("Ingrese el dia(DD), luego el mes(MM) y por ultimo el anio de la persona(AAAA): \n");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dia );
    while((*puntero_persona).dia < 1 || (*puntero_persona).dia > 31){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un dia correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dia );
            }
    printf("Dia ingresado correctamente\n");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).mes );
    while((*puntero_persona).mes < 1 || (*puntero_persona).mes > 12){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un mes correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).mes );
            }
    printf("Mes ingresado correctamente\n");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).anio );
    while((*puntero_persona).anio < 1921 || (*puntero_persona).anio > 2021){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un anio correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).anio );
            }
    printf("Anio ingresado correctamente\n");
}

void menu(){
    printf("\nUsted se encuentra en el menu, ingrese una opcion a realizar\n");
    printf("\n1 - Para ingresar personas a su agenda\n2 - Para ver un listado general de personas ingresadas\n"
           "3 - Para ver un listado de todas las personas nacidas en un anio especifico\n4 - Si desea ver quien"
           "es la persona mas joven de todo el listado\n5 - Si desea editar los datos de una persona especifica\n"
           "6 - Si desea ver los datos de una persona en particular\n7 - Si desea buscar una persona por DNI\n"
           "8 - Para salir de su agenda\nRespuesta: ");
}

int opcion, cantidad, i;

int main(){
    bool flag;
    flag = true;

    printf("Bienvenido a su agenda\n");
    while(flag == true){
        menu();
        scanf("%d",&opcion);


        if(opcion < 1 || opcion > 8) {
            printf("Opcion invalida, elija un numero correcto: ");
            scanf("%d",&opcion);
        }else if(opcion == 1){
            printf("Cuantas personas va a querer ingresar al sistema? Minimo 1, maximo 100\nRespuesta: ");
            scanf("%d",&cantidad);

            while(cantidad < 1 || cantidad > 100){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un numero correcto: ");
                scanf("%d",&cantidad);
            }
            for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++ ){
                cargar(&personas[i]);
                printf("Persona cargada correctamente\n");
            }
            printf("Gracias por cargar personas a la agenda, sera direccionado al menu\n");
        }else if(opcion == 2){
            printf("\nLista de personas agendadas: \n");
            for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++ ){
            mostrar(personas[i]);
            }
            printf("\nLista terminada, sera guiado al menu de nuevo\n");
        }

//Recorte el codigo hasta la opcion 2
```

Comment: Entre otros problemas , el error te dale por `(*puntero_persona).dni[j+1])`. `dni` es de tipo entero y tú estás tomando como si rue a un arreglo.

Comment: Quizá es `puntero_persona[j+1].dni`. el `j+1]` no sé si debe ser así porque cuando llegues al último va a darte un error. Los arrays siempre empiezan en 0 por eso los `for` tiene la condición `<`.

Comment: Recomiendo hacer la búsqueda no recorriendo el arreglo sino recorriendo un arból donde los índices estén indexados (el comportamiento asintótico se reduce de `O(n)` a `O(log(n))`) o bien, sacar el prehash de varios dni y cuando te ingresen un dni checar si su prehash no existe ya (el comportamiento asintótico se reduce de `O(n)` a `O(1)`). Ambos serían buenos ejercicios y lo mejor es que **tienen aplicaciones reales**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL problema esta acá: `(*puntero_persona).dni[j]`. EL problema es que `dni` ya es un número entero. Además de lo anterior, es necesario almancenar el número de personas actualmente existente en una variable `npersonas`. FInalmente, al leer strings con scanf no se debe usar el caracter `&`.

Debería ser así:

```
c_persona personas[100];
int npersonas = 0;

void cargar(c_persona *puntero_persona){
    int contenedor, j;
    char contenido = 0;
    
    if (npersonas == 100)
    {
        printf("Numero de personas excede el maximo permitido");
        return;
    }

    printf("Ingrese el nombre de la persona: ");
    scanf("%s", (*puntero_persona).nombre );
    printf("Ingrese el apellido de la persona: ");
    scanf("%s", (*puntero_persona).apellido );
    printf("Ingrese el dni de la persona: ");


    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dni );
    while((*puntero_persona).dni < 10000000 || (*puntero_persona).dni > 99999999){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un dni correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dni );
            }

    while (true)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<npersonas;j++){
            if(contenedor == personas[j].dni){
                contenido = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!contenido)
            break;
        printf("DNI repetido, vuelva a ingresar el dni correctamente: ");
        scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dni );
        contenedor = (*puntero_persona).dni;
        contenido = 0;
    }
 
    printf("Ingrese el telefono de la persona: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).tel );
    while((*puntero_persona).tel < 1000000000 || (*puntero_persona).tel > 9999999999){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un telefono correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).tel );
            }
    printf("Ingrese el dia(DD), luego el mes(MM) y por ultimo el anio de la persona(AAAA): \n");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dia );
    while((*puntero_persona).dia < 1 || (*puntero_persona).dia > 31){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un dia correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).dia );
            }
    printf("Dia ingresado correctamente\n");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).mes );
    while((*puntero_persona).mes < 1 || (*puntero_persona).mes > 12){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un mes correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).mes );
            }
    printf("Mes ingresado correctamente\n");
    scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).anio );
    while((*puntero_persona).anio < 1921 || (*puntero_persona).anio > 2021){
                printf("Opcion invalida, elija un anio correcto: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*puntero_persona).anio );
            }
    printf("Anio ingresado correctamente\n");
    npersonas = npersonas+1;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, me resolviste el error del dni entero, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me sigue sin funcionar ya que cuando termina la vuelta del for me lo vuelve a encontrar. https://prnt.sc/159gy2g

Comment: @mati, modifiqué mi respuesta

Comment: Vi tu respuesta y lo quise llevar al código pero al momento de ingresar una nueva persona, sea lo que sea que ponga me vuelve a dar DNI repetido:( pero ya con tu respuesta voy a intentar arreglarlo porque me sirve para guiarme, muchas gracias de todas manera por tus respuestas y tus ayudas!

Comment: Se me fue colocar esto: dentro del ciclo while: `contenido = 0;`. Espero que ahora sí funcione.

Comment: De todos modos espero que mi ayuda te pueda hacer servido de algo. Saludos.

Comment: Si! Luego viendo el codigo vi que tenia que poner eso y me habia olvidado de entrar a contestarlo, muchas gracias por todo